# LocationSettings for Google places api to detect current location

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to use google places api to detect current location of the device using PlaceDetectionApi.
I was expecting that in case needed settings are not enabled to detect the current place, starting resolution should prompt the user to enable location services without the need to build LocationSettings object and calling it explicitly for resolution.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the location mode disabled or not manually and if disabled you can open settings directly to enable it as Shown:

```
 public static boolean isLocationServicesAvailable(Context context) {
        int locationMode = 0;
        String locationProviders;
        boolean isAvailable = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            isAvailable = (locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
        } else {
            locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            isAvailable = !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
        }

        // boolean coarsePermissionCheck = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        // boolean finePermissionCheck = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        return isAvailable;
    }
```

**openening settings in case of disabled:**

```
if(!isLocationServicesAvailable(this)) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setMessage("enabled");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("open GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    //get gps
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: I was hoping that there's a better generic resolution instead of checking for internet and gps manually